# SQL Server conversion string to date

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with conversion string to date. The thing is, I create the table, and I got database with a plenty of records, and I should load it to my table. I searched any solution but I found only with SELECT or CONVERT but singular record.

This is the error msg:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How I should fix it for many records (SQL Server)?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Are you trying to load data from one table into another, converting a varchar to a datetime?  Can you supply sample data?

Comment: no, I go file with smt like that(this is an example):
INSERT INTO database_name.dbo.table_name
VALUES('Smith','John','1965-10-21','1999-06-11'),
... (repeat)..

Comment: there are about 2.000 records so I need a solution with I can use on all these at once

Comment: I'm still a little confused -- what's not working?  Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bccfd/1

Comment: +1 All look fine to me too. Please show us your table definition.

Comment: I do this like in this example, and I have this error again and again. I don't know where it can be a problem, I check the table and this file. All of this should be fine, but it isn't.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Pracownicy
(
 id int IDENTITY(1,1),
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 nazwisko varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 imie varchar NOT NULL,
 data_ur date NOT NULL,
 data_zatr date NOT NULL,
 
)

Comment: You can use ISDate in a case construct like here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e84d7/2

Comment: I can't use SELECT, I created a table, and i should put into this table about 2000 records.

Comment: @Maggie -- I think we're still a little confused about your requirements.  Perhaps you could edit your question with additional details -- what's not working?  Show us what you've tried, and possibly with a SQL Fiddle example.

Comment: Ok, I'll try
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b699/1/0 this is how I created a table, next I'll try to put the records into my table, here I get a few, but I have about 2000 rows. When I try execute this I get msg:
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. 
and I don't know why and what I can do to put the rows into my table. ( I hope it's more clear now.)

Comment: Thanks for building the Fiddle.  So are you getting the error on specific insert statements -- some work, some don't?  Did you write the insert statements or can those be altered?  If they can be altered, I have a solution for you I think.

Comment: ok, thank you, it works :D I didn't think about it earlier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had wrong order of columns, so it take name as date, and try to convert varchar to date. I do appreciate you help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question , you have an issue with one or some of your insert statements.  Assuming you can alter the `INSERT` statements, then you can use `ISDATE` as suggested by a previous commenter:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES('Lisiak','Anna',
    CASE WHEN ISDATE('1968-05')=1 THEN '1968-05' ELSE '1/1/1753' END,
    CASE WHEN ISDATE('1998-01-01')=1 THEN '1998-01-01' ELSE '1/1/1753' END);
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c7e6/1)

Since you're fiddle example had the date fields as not null, I used 1/1/1753 for invalid dates -- change accordingly.

If you cannot alter your `INSERT` statements for whatever reason, another option would be to alter your table to accept varchar instead of datetime.  Then convert and alter back accordingly.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET data_ur = CASE WHEN ISDATE(data_ur)=1 THEN data_Ur ELSE '1/1/1753' END;

ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN data_ur DATE NOT NULL;
```

[Another Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ab24/1)

Comment: Yes, but if I have about 2000 rows, it's quite difficult add this to every of them. It's good when you have not so much record to insert.